# Not able to import MariaDB dump file to Azure Maria DB

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I m getting below error while importing database to Azure Maria DB through MySQl Workbench

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1746: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`json_object`,'$.attribute_cod...' at line 6

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1KCy.png)

Comment: Copy/paste the error as TEXT in your question (see: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) )   And show the code that is causing this error.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1746: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`json_object`,'$.attribute_cod...' at line 6

Comment: Please, ".... And show the code that is causing this error" ?  How can someone help when you do not tell what you are doing, and how you are trying to do it?   HOW are your doing the import dump ?  What statement are you using ? You should share that statement because it's the cause of this error.